# Dialing keypad sounds like a rubber ducky with each number pressed....yeah

Tags: samsung

Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra. Instead of the normal DTMF tones, his phone is squeaking like a rubber duck with each number pressed on the dial key pad. No idea how it got this way or how to fix it. He doesn't want to completely get rid of the tone, just wants the normal one back!!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it

Settings> Sounds and Vibration> System Sound > Choose "Galaxy"

Mine was set to "Fun"

Thanks.